# How can entropy be concave in time?

Tags: convex-optimization, entropy, ricci-flow, gradient-flows

At [this point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo46TEp6FB8&t=3573s) in a lecture by Cedric Villani, prof. Villani talks about his work revealing that "if entropy is a concave function of time, then the Ricci curvature is non-negative."

But wait, how can entropy be concave in time? Doesn't the 2nd law of thermodynamics insist that entropy is monotonically increasing in time?

Comment: $\log$ is monotonically increasing, and concave.

Comment: Ah, I see he did not draw a monotonic function. Still, concavity and monotonicity can coexist.